# how to post on a facebook event wall?

Tags: php, facebook

Im new at facebook app development and I am trying to make an automatic post on an event wall. I have read that include the id to post on a specific wall. I have tried that but it doesn't work.

I thought that maybe it would work with "to" (a specific targeted wall), but I don't know it's syntax...

can anyone help? or at least give an example of a post syntax with a "to" property included... plssss...

Comment: You have to ask for permissions from the user first in order to do "automatic" posts.

Answer (score 3):

```
$attachment = array(
                'message' => 'this is my message',
                'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
                'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
                'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
                'description' => 'this is a description',
                'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif',
                'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
                'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
                );
$uid = ""; //friend id OR "me"
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

---

> - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

---

**NOTE**: you should have the user [publish_stream extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) and you should have the [SDK Lib](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure that this actually answers the question posed. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the above code will actually post to the user's news feed.. not to an event's wall. I'm also fairly certain simply substituting in the event's ID in for the user's ID in the above code won't work either.

Comment: @kai: the method "feed" Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall, for the rest it will work just read the API DOC and follow the rabbit. hope this help! ;) http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: thank you very much for the help! I appreciate for your time...^_^

Comment: well, i got that the question is about how to post on event wall; and the answer is about how to post on a user wall. It is wrong answer for me.

Comment: @darlinton: dear, please pay attention to the comment i have done to @kai ( above ). thank's.

Comment: @aSeptik: 'Follow the rabbit' is very vague.  The point of this site is to get quick answers without having to page through API docs.  Let me spell it out: $facebook->api('<eventID>/feed/','post',$attachment);  A simple curl command would be:  curl -d "access_token=<accessToken>&message=<YourMessage>" https ://graph.facebook.com/<eventID>/feed

Answer (score 0):

```
$attachment = array(
                'message' => 'this is my message'
                );
$eid = ""; //event id
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$eid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ <-- event object documentation

or

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?message=<your_message>&target_id=<event_id>&access_token=<your_token>
```